Exercise IV 2.8 in "New Kunen" (Set Theory).
So, I am learning about the most basic setup to get forcing on the ground, and I  feel like I want to understand the recursively defined notion \begin{align*} \text{val}(\tau,G) &:= \{\text{val}(\sigma,G): \exists p \in G(\langle \sigma,p \rangle \in \tau)\}\\
&:= \tau_G,\end{align*} better, where $\tau$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-name, $G$ is a $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter over $M$, where $M$ is a c.t.m. model of $\sf{ZFC}$ (or perhaps just some finite fragment of $\sf{ZFC}$ needed).
In Kunens more recently published "Set Theory/Studies in Logic", he gives the following exercise (I'll make the identification $\varnothing := 0$):

Let $\tau = \{\langle 0,p \rangle,\langle \{\langle 0,q \rangle \},r\rangle\}$. Compute $\tau_G$ for each of the $8$ possibilities for $p,q,r$ being $\in$ or $\not \in G$.

$\textbf{Question}$: Is $\text{val}(0,G) = 0$ a definition? I believe the answer here is positive.
$\underline{p \in G,q,r \not \in G}$:
Here, $\tau_G =  \{0\}$.
$\underline{p,q \in G, r \not \in G}$:
Same answer as above.
$\underline{p,q,r \not \in G}$:
Answer I believe to be just $0$, there are no relations for which there is some element $p \in G$ so that $\langle 0,p \rangle \in \tau$ holds.
$\underline{p,r \in G,q \not \in G}$:
We get \begin{align*} \text{val}(\tau,G) &= \{\text{val}(0,G),\text{val}(\{\langle 0,q \rangle\},G)\}\\
&= \{0,0\}\\
&= \{0\}.
 \end{align*}
since $q \not \in G$.
$\underline{r \in G,p,q \not \in G}$: $\{0\}$.
$\underline{q,r \in G, p \not \in G}$:
We have \begin{align*} \tau_G 
&= \{\text{val}(\{\langle 0,q\rangle\},G)\}\\
&= \{\{0\}\}.\end{align*}
$\underline{q \in G, p,r \not \in G}$: This gives us $0$.
$\underline{p,q,r \in G}$: By earlier calculations, this is $\{0,\{0\}\}$.
Is this correct, or have I completely misunderstood the definition?

It's true that $\operatorname{val}({\langle 0,p\rangle}, G) = {0}$ when $p\in G,$ but that's not ever something you are to evaluate when computing $\tau_G.$ In the case $p\in G,$ $q,r\notin G,$ $\tau_G = {0},$ not ${{0}},$ and similarly most of your answers have one too many brackets.

Why though? I mean, I am just following the definitions. Hmm. Why do you say ”that’s not something you ever are to evaluate when computing $\tau_G$”?

Oh, right, I see.

@spaceisdarkgreen I've corrected some (most?) of them (hopefully).

$\tau$ has 2 possible elements. The first possible element, activated by $p$, is $0$, the second possible element, activated by $r$ is ${\langle 0,q\rangle}$, which has one possible element, activated by $q$ which is $0$ (i.e. it's either $0$ or ${0}$).  So The answers should all be amongst $0,$ ${0},$ ${{0}},$ ${0,0}={0},$ and ${0,{0}}.$

yes, I agree. I've again (sigh...) corrected it.
